# How to decide the weight of Luma and Chroma distortion in the RDO process?

Tags: hevc, rdo

In the HEVC reference software HM, in the RDO process, the distortion contains the luma and chroma, and they have different weights. Through debugging the codes, I find the chroma weight is higher than 1. So does anyone know how to decide the the weights? Are there any papers talking about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question.
This topic is discussed in the proposal JCT-VC F386. It is about the RDO of Chroma.